# defending against .html and .php file name guessing

Tags: php, html, security

If certain .html files can only be accessed by a password match (implemented in PHP) to a hash code in a database, the user can still guess likely .html file names and see that supposedly privileged page. Viewing the source of the privileged page, the user can then see the name of a .php that is invoked in that .html which might lead to the guessing of the likely POST arguments.

What is the best practice to reduce the temptation to do this type of guessing of names both of the .html and .php file types.

The .htaccess file already has "options -indexes" to prevent listing directories.

Edit: ummm,instead of upvoting that it's a bad implementation, why not upvote one of the suggested answers or write a new one. It's obvious that it's a bad implementation, that's why this question was posted.

Comment: It's actually a very bad implementation, if guessing something like filenames can provide useful results!

Comment: Did you take a look at other "security" implementations? HTTP Auth?

Comment: They would only be able to accomplish vandalism, nothing useful.

Comment: IkoTikashi, this is a small project and my initial impression was that I could do it all in .PHP and MySQL without any additional packages. If I'm wrong, then this question will have served a purpose for me.

Comment: You CAN do this with only PHP and MySQL, it's just your CURRENT implementation that is very insecure.

Comment: the simplest one is to have all php pages, with a small authentication detection snippet on top of them.

Comment: You know that you can instruct Apache to treat `.html` files as PHP; if you don't already know. So, why the use of `.html` files if you're using `.php` in conjunction with it?

Comment: I didn't know that. By treating them as .PHP how does that solve the problem? They could still guess .PHP files. Harder to do without help of HTML source, of course.

Comment: If you do includes instead, and load content from it, then you won't have to show them `.php` extension files.

Comment: I think the solution I like best is to make a session with the suggestion from STT LCU which would have me querying the database at the top of each file to make sure the session is still in "authenticated" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the comments and suggested answers has me thinking that a good solution is to have every file that needs security query the database to determine if the "authenticated" state still applies at this point in time.

Implement the "per request check" as described [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/PHP_Programming/Building_a_secure_user_login_system) wherever there is a vulnerability.

If STT LCU will convert his comment into a posted answer, I will delete this answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you only ever include these pages inside other pages, deny access to them in .htaccess
2. If you want them to be accessible, but only to authorized users, password protect it or provide other authentcation

Preventing people guessing the name of a page is "security through obscurity", which should never be relied upon. Set your system up with that assumption that everything is visible, and work your security out from that

Comment: I do use password protection, as already mentioned, so I am not purely relying upon obscurity. This question is to help me get to the next level of security.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to defend yourself from filename guessing, but still being able to provide that pages to some users is to leverage user accounts, logins and authenthications.

Other than that, you can set `.htaccess` to `deny` from all IP's, with some exceptions.

Comment: As mentioned, I already do authenticate to a hash code in a database table. It doesn't do a session though and perhaps a session is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

to do that you need to use some kind of router.

I highly recommend slim framewrok, but you can easily develop your one.

First restrict all the .html and .php files in htaccess except of the main index.php (or however you want to call it).

Then in index.php you check if user is allowed to see the file. If yes you include the file in outpout if not show 404.

In slim you can easily use ready made `middlewares` for authentications.

http://docs.slimframework.com/ to learn more about routing.

http://docs.slimframework.com/#Middleware-Overview to learn about middleware

https://github.com/tuupola/slim-basic-auth/ for simple authentication and examples.